# Events: list is returning items as a empty array even though there are lot of events present in my calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am hitting events list api on my primary calendar using https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list, but the response I get is as below -

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"p32cepg73vamue0g\"",
 "summary": "xxxxx@gmail.com",
 "updated": "2020-01-31T13:37:23.519Z",
 "timeZone": "Asia/Calcutta",
 "accessRole": "owner",
 "defaultReminders": [
  {
   "method": "popup",
   "minutes": 30
  },
  {
   "method": "email",
   "minutes": 30
  }
 ],
 "nextPageToken": "CigKGnRwaDY1ajllNm5ldmRtcjJkMmlyMmlwNm40GAEggICA5OuK7f8WGg0IABIAGJjswOP6recCIgcIAhCKnqEB",
 "items": []
}
```

There are a lot of events created in my Calendar, but I am not getting any items returned from the API.[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code not just the response

Comment: Are you specifying any other parameters than `calendarId` (and if yes - which)? Do you have only one calendar? Maybe your events are in a different calendar than the one you are listing the events for?

Comment: @DaImTo don't have my own code as I am using the "Try this API" section on UI of page https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list to try out the request . I am passing calendarId=primary and getting the response posted in the question.

Comment: @ziganotschka I am only passing calendarId=primary.  The events are in my primary calendar. Not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: Are you signed into Chrome with multiple accounts? This could make you retrieve the events from the wrong primary calendar.